# Focal Fossa 20.04 LTS and realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms

Tags: 20.04, realtek

Is there a way to install the realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms driver on focal fossa? I did an apt-get update and it appears not to be in the repositories. I'm new to Linux, especially installing drivers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no "88xx". You must use a real number. For example, `rtl8812au-dkms` is package in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the kali repo to Ubuntu to be able to do this (not advised).
For using the driver it is better to compile from source on GitHub and use dkms.

Answer (score 0):

This just short Tutorial for NEWBIE (like me!) for installing driver USB Wifi driver for Linux Debian and it’s derivatives (Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Pop! OS, Elementary OS, etc.)

When you're switch to new OS distro or updating OS or accidently delete some part of software sometimes your Wifi driver are no support / no working and got blank your mind ... Yup thats right !

**First STEP to do :**

1. You only need YOUR SMARTPHONES and make sure also they have “Internet Mobile Data”.
2. Then you need to opened “Developer Options” on your smartphone to do that first before.
3. Open your phone “Settings” and find it “About Phone” and selected “Version Number” and then now repeated click up to (7x) seven times.
4. Inside “Developer Options” find it or scrolling to the “Network” and selected “Select USB Configuration” and then select again to the “USB Ethernet (RNDIS)”.
5. After this all you need is USB cable connected to your PC or Laptop and it’s done, now you ready online!

**Second STEP to do :**

1. Installing GDebi (I’m using Geary on Pop! OS that are the same software). You can find GDebi in Ubuntu Software Center,  just search for it and install it from there.
2. Then installing the latest “realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms” deb package from Kali’s repository.
3. After this just type in your linux terminal “sudo reboot” to rebooting your PC or Laptop.
4. It’s done , just try to check it out !

I’m trying many times using this method when i switching to new OS distros or update Linux Kernel. This really saving my times and work to do! Thanks for your time to read this !

**Source :**

- https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/contrib/r/realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms/
- https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options
- https://itsfoss.com/gdebi-default-ubuntu-software-center/